# Rejecting buffered Puts in HBase HTable instance (while having the autoFlush set on false)?

Tags: java, hbase

I'm writing a Java app communicating with the HBase via the [Java HBase client (version 0.94.16)][1]. On the `HTable` instance I've already set the `setAutoFlush` on false so that the `Put`s would be buffered instead of flushed after each call of the `put` method. I use this `Put` buffer to collect the related data so they could be flushed together at once calling the `flushCommits` method. But there is a situation in my app (in the middle of data collection) when I find that these related data cannot be completed so I want to clear the `Put`s buffer that has been filled instead of flushing of incomplete data set.

So my question is: *Is there any efficient way (within Java HBase client) how to clear the Puts buffer (discard the data in it) of `HTable` instance (without flushing)?* I know how to implement this Puts buffer on my own, but I would love to see some solution within bounds of Java HBase Client. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BufferedMutator](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/BufferedMutator.html)
doesn't seem to have anything that discards the Put buffer outside of a JVM or machine failure..

I think the only way is to make your own PutBuffer

```
public class PutBuffer {
    public PutBuffer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {…}
    public void setFlushTimeout(int millis) {…}
    public int getFlushTimeout() {…}
    public void addPut(TableName table, Put put) {…}
    public void discardBuffer(TableName table) {…}
    public void flush() {…}
}
```